# Is it possible to do DateAdd calculations in Linq to Entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities, dateadd

I have the following sql and I'm not sure how to do a DateAdd and an IsNull in Linq to Entities.  Is this even possible?

```
Select TOP 1 DateAdd(MINUTE, 
    (IsNull(AlarmMinutes, 0) * -1) + (IsNull(SnoozeMinutes, 0)), 
    DueDate) 
From Todo
Order By DateAdd(MINUTE, 
    (IsNull(AlarmMinutes, 0) * -1) + (IsNull(SnoozeMinutes, 0)), 
    DueDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EnitityFunctions.AddMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395560%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var date = (from x in context.Todo
            let AlarmMinutes = x.AlarmMinutes.HasValue ? x.AlarmMinutes.Value : 0
            let SnoozeMinutes= x.SnoozeMinutes.HasValue ? x.SnoozeMinutes.Value : 0
            let newDate = EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(x.DueDate, AlarmMinutes*-1 + SnoozeMinutes)
            ordeby newDate
            select newDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Almost worked perfectly.  I had to modify this line EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(x.DueDate, AlarmMinutes*-1 + SnoozeMinutes) to EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(x.DueDate, (AlarmMinutes ?? 0)*-1 + (SnoozeMinutes ?? 0))

Comment: EntityFuntions is now called DbFunctions